# To create a persistant variable is it better to have a local static variable or a global?

Tags: c++, c, static

Lets say you have a class (c++) or module (single c file). Then in one of your functions you want to store a copy of a variable and hold its value until the next time the function is called, is it better to have a global (could be private in c++ and not extern'd in c to keep it in the module scope) or make a local static variable?

e.g.:

```
void some_func_that_does_not_do_anything_useful(int arbVal)
{
    static int lastArbVal = 0;

    if (arbVal > lastArbVal)
    {
        lastArbVal = arbVal;
    }
}
```

The reason I would make a static is to keep its scope as limited as possible, but certain things I read suggest you should use globals for this, so now I am confused.

What is best (if any)?, pros/cons?

Comment: If you only use it in that function, and nowhere else, then making it `static` is probably the best solution. Though you might want to think about cases like multi-threading, as the static variable will be shared between all threads.

Comment: In the interest of encapsulation a local static would be best. This is also the approach many C functions take. `strtok` comes to mind.

Comment: To quote from the `strtok` man page: "Never use these functions". Let's not use that as an example of how to do things :-)

Comment: Can you share the resource/s from where you read that you should use globals in this case?

Comment: No the example shows pretty much how I have it in my code. Its all within this one function and not used anywhere else :)

Comment: What purpose of the lastArbVal variable?

Comment: @zabulus in this example (which is pointless) nothing much. In my real code "lastArbVal" would remember that last value so that I can find the difference between the current value and the previous value and do actions accordingly

Comment: If the function need to be accessed by multiple thread, another benefit of static function level variable is the C++ standard define it as thread safe, and most compiler have option to make it thread safe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rule here is simple: if the variable needs to be accessed by more than one functions, make it global. If not, `static` variables inside functions are usually better. One of the pros is it avoids polluting the global namespace.

Note that if a global variable doesn't need to be accessed outside the file, it's better to declare it as file-scope variable(i.e, declare it as `static`)

Back to your example, I think it's best to use `static` variable like you already did.

Comment: An alternative to file-scope `static` is an anonymous namespace.

Comment: One more reason file scope `static` might not be suitable is static initialization order. If the function that uses it is called during initialization of other statics from different translation units, then you're in for trouble.